# Override default get_absolute_url on User objects?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-authentication

I'm trying to make a generic table for listing [`django_tables`](http://github.com/dgelvin/django-tables) objects.  I've got everything working, except that the `get_absolute_urls()` on my `User` objects returns:

```
/users/<username>/
```

While I could create this URL, it doesn't match with the rest of the site layout, so I'm looking for another way to do this.  Is there a way to override this value without breaking the built in authentication and other functionality?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do this in your settings.py file using the setting `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES`

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: "/users/%s/" % u.username,
}
```

Here's a link to the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/

Comment: Brilliant!  The settings file was the one place I didn't look for this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*As a side note:*

**Since django v1.7 the `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` no longer defines a `get_absolute_url()` method (see [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.7/)).**

So the OP's problem will not exist with django > v1.7 as you anyways need to define your custom [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) method.

Now there are two way to do this:

1. Define a `get_absolute_url()` method in your User model extension.
2. Use the solution from [Mark Lavin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328856/1622937) to create (not overwrite) the `User.get_absolute_url()` through the [`ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES) setting.

Comment: Hi. Could you elaborate a little? What do you mean by User model extension, where can I put my new user model e.g. `class UserTmp(User):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/user/{self.id}/"` to?